# Как сделать кнопку Tkinter так чтобы она открывала другое окно?

Tags: python, tkinter, datetime

Вот код:

```
 from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('270x450')

button_1 = Button(text='Часы', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'))
button_1.place(x=50, y=50)

button_2 = Button(text='Календарь', width=12, height=6, font=('Roman 8'))
button_2.place(x=150, y=50)

button_3 = Button(text='Настройки', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 9'))
button_3.place(x=50, y=150)

button_4 = Button(text='Игра', width=10, height=5, font=('Roman 10'))
button_4.place(x=150, y=150)

window.mainloop()
```

А это код приложения, которая кнопка должна открывать:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Часы")
a = Label(root, font=("Gabriola", 20))


def update_time():
    root.geometry('270x450+{}+{}'.format(500, 400))
    a.config(text=f"{datetime.now():%H:%M:%S}")
    root.after(100, update_time)

a = Label(root, font=("helvetica", 40))
a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
update_time()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Второе окно создавать через tk.Toplevel вместо tk.Tk, убрать второй mainloop (должен быть только один главный цикл), обернуть создание окна в функцию, которую вызывать из первого окна.

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/ru/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-create-a-new-window-with-a-button-in-tkinter/ посмотрите это